# How To Create WooCommerce Custom Template For Specific Product?

Tags: templates, woocommerce-offtopic, e-commerce

I know this may be slightly off topic, but this really is the best place to ask a question related to WooCommerce & WordPress.

I've search high and low for an answer to this question and there does not seem to be one.

I have a specific product under the category 'course'. I would like to create a custom template for this product which I can drop into my themes template files.

What would I need to name the file for it to override on this specific product only?

- single-product-[slug].php
- single-product-[category].php
- single-product-[pageid].php
- single-product-[productid].php

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

Override the template with a [template_include](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) filter.

Answer (score 1):

you need to check the last specifications from woocommerce to override his template files.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

The last time i did it, i copy the template file with the structure of the folder from the woo plugins template directory under the active theme inside a folder named woocommerce with the same structure. You can get more info in the above link.

Answer (score 0):

As woocommerce is basically just posts have you not tried single-productID.php so single-234.php

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Yes it does it states that if you add single- and the post / product id the it is specific for that post if you try it then you will see that does exactly what he is asking for

Comment: Please elaborate on the answer. I can understand how this is a genuine attempt to provide an answer but it is phrased as a question, albeit a carelessly punctuated one.

Comment: Basically copy single-product.php and rename to single-[productid].php and upload in your theme folder